# WCF jQuery receiving list data from server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf

I am trying to use jQuery + Ajax + WCF... Can you help me with it? If I use single data response in WCF it is ok, but when I try to send a list or massive as a response from WCF it looks wrong.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace longpollingexample
{
    [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.NotAllowed)]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public class Service2
    {          
        static List<int> ff = new List<int>();

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public List<int> hi(int a, int f)
        {
            ff.Add(a*f);
            return ff;
        }
    }
}
```

This is WCF service, we have only one function and try to get answer to list. List is static. How can I get any elements from this list? What I try to do...

```
  function hi2() {
        var t = 0;
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            url: '/Service2.svc/hi',
            data: 'a= ' + $('#my1').val() + '&f=' + $('#my2').val(),
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var str='';
                str += data[0].d;
                $("#msgs").html(aa);
            },
            error: function () { alert('pop the champagne'); }
        });
    }
```

Can I get `data[0].d` - the first element from my ff list? It is doesn't work (what's wrong? Thanks! Sorry for my english, i know it is really bad(

Comment: is that work for you ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do like this ,

```
 success: function (data) {
  $.each(data.d, function(i, item) {
         alert(item);
   });
 }
```

Comment: Yes, but can i work with data like massive data[0], data[1] and so on?

Comment: @KarenLi - i m not sure but you can work like data.d[0], data.d[1] ...etc bcasue in data.d you have you json object which you need to rotate as i did in my code ...direct data[0] is not possible..you can check documentation for this on jquery site ..